# For a finitely generated group $F$, why is $[F,F]/[F,[F,F]]$ finitely generated?

Tags: group-theory

I believe that given a finitely generated group $F$, the quotient of the $i$th center by the $(i+1)$th center is finitely generated.

For example, $[F,F]/[F,[F,F]]$ should be finitely generated.

How do we see this? For example, in the case where $F$ is the free group of rank 2, $[F,F]$ is infinitely generated, so it's not immediately clear that $[F,F]/[F,[F,F]]$ should be finitely generated.

Comment: Prove that $F/\gamma_{i+1}(F)$ is generated by the images of $[x_i,y_j]$, where the $x_i$ generate $F$ and the images of $y_i$ generate $F/\gamma_i(F)$. Then the result follows by induction. This is essentially equivalent to the result that all subgroups of finitely generated nilpotent groups are finitely generated.

Comment: @DerekHolt Nice! Feel free to post it as an answer so I can mark this question answered.

Answer (score 2):

Derek's comment is of course the way to go, but here's an easy way to see this particular case is true:

If $x,y,z$ are generators of $F$, then note that

\begin{align}
[xy,z] &= [x,y]^z[z,y]\\
&= [x,y][z,y]\pmod{[F,F,F]}
\end{align}

since $[z,[y,x]]=[x,y]^z[y,x]$.

Of course the same can be done for $[x,yz]$. So if $u$ and $v$ are any words in the generators of $F$, then we can write $[u,v]$ -- using the above repeatedly -- as a product of commutators of generators of $F$, all of course mod $[F,F,F]$.

Thus $[F,F]/[F,F,F]$ is generated by $[a,b]$ for $a,b$ generators of $F$.

Comment: Can you say what $[A,B,C]$ means?

Comment: @WillChen: sure, it's the subgroup $[[A,B],C]=[C,[A,B]]$.